# C# Elastic Search - Need to add new parameter to Elastic index object and set its default value to all the other objects

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I am new to c# and Elastic search. I have a user profile index where I have to add "isActive" boolean parameter in C# application. I am trying to add an implementation to get the users who has isActive flag set to True and the users who do not have this flag at all in the Elastic query from c#. but unable to get the exact query to add to the current getUsers search query.

I am trying to create an Elastic query from C# where isActive attribute is not present in the user object or isActive is true.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: basically you want to filter users based in `isActive` flag, would it be OK i can provide the search query in JSON format, as I am not familiar with c# syntax but it should be pretty straight forward if you already have some filters in your code and once search JSON works fine for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need should clause(OR) with a term query to check IsActive ==true and a must_not clause to check if field exists

```
var searchResponse = _elasticClient.Search<Project>(s => s
                    .Query(q => q
                    .Bool(b => b
                        .Should(
                                    sh => sh.Term(t => t.IsActive, true),
                                    sh => sh.Bool(bl => bl.MustNot(mn => mn.Exists(e => e.Field(et => et.IsActive)))))
                                )
                          )
                    )
```